# How to find out which entity in a collection (OneToMany association ) launched an exception constraint violation in a JPA persist operation?

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entities, A and B, linked by a bi-directional OneToMany association (one A, many Bs). In my business code I have something like that:

```
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, 1L);

List<B> bs = ...; //populate some "bs" here

try{
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  a.setBs(bs);
  for (B b : bs) {
    b.setA(a);
  }
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
} (PersistenceException e) {
   entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
   // Ultimately, a ConstraintViolationException may hapen if a b already exists.
}
```

How to find out, in the catch block above, which entity caused the constraint violation (unique key violation in some b, indeed) to feedback the user with a better message of the problem?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1: the violated constraint is a unique key in "bs" entities, nothing wrong happens to the "a" entity.

UPDATE 2: I figured out a way how to identify the entity that threw the CVException. This is my new code:

```
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, 1L);

List<B> bs = ...; //populate some "bs" here

try{
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  a.setBs(bs);
  B nonUniqueB= null;
  for (B b : bs) {
    nonUniqueB= b;
    b.setA(a);
    entityManager.persist(b);
    entityManager.flush();    //anticipates the sql that will violate the unique constraint. Without it, the exception will be thrown by the commit() method, when I have no way to know which entity violated the unique.
  }
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
} (PersistenceException e) {
   entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();

   // Iterate over the stacktrace to find a CVException
   Throwable t = ex.getCause();
   while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
     t = t.getCause();
   }
   if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
      //deals with nonUniqueB
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about primary key violation , it's because JPA is trying to insert the 'a object'

```
A a = entityManager.findById(1L);
```

If you have a bi-directional association with cascade-persist option on the many-to-one side. The problem is ,if you create a new instance of B which contains an object retrieved from the database `b.setA(a);`  JPA will see the 'object a' as new instance when it call insert operation `em.persist(b);` and with the cascade-persist option will cause `em.persist(a);`

Solution : delete the cascade-persist from the many-to-one side or insert the new instance of 'B' `em.persist(b);` and then `b.setA(a);`

Comment: Sorry SEY_91, I informed the wrong exception. In fact, it is a unique key violation in some "b" entity. The "a" entity is not violating any primary key and the cascades are working well. Thank you for your response.